# XYRATEX HB-1235 Complete Array Dropping

Tags: zfs, solaris

I have an XYRATEX HB-1235 connected to a Solaris 11.4 system via a single SAS cable to an LSI controller. The drives in the array are SATA.

Every now and then, possibly due to a slight power flicker (yes, it's on a UPS), the entire array drops, corrupting all active zpools on the array. ZFS is great, but rip out an entire array and it gets a little finicky.

The error I get on Solaris is something like this:

> fmd: [ID 377184 daemon.notice] SUNW-MSG-ID: FMD-8000-CV, TYPE: Alert,
> VER: 1, SEVERITY: Minor#012EVENT-TIME: Mon Dec 5 15:09:02 EST
> 2022#012PLATFORM: To be filled by O.E.M., CSN: To be filled by O.E.M.,
> HOSTNAME: mm001#012SOURCE: software-diagnosis, REV: 0.2#012EVENT-ID:
> 42c92c4a-58a8-4af8-99b8-b38e94799475#012DESC: FRU
> '/XYRATEX-HB-1235-E6EBD.50050cc10a102b32/' has been removed from the
> system.#012AUTO-RESPONSE: FMD topology will be updated.#012IMPACT:
> System impact depends on the type of FRU.#012REC-ACTION: Please refer
> to the associated reference document at
> http://support.oracle.com/msg/FMD-8000-CV for the latest service
> procedures and policies regarding this diagnosis.#012FRU-LOCATION:
> /XYRATEX-HB-1235-E6EBD.50050cc10a102b32/

I read somewhere in the past (can't find it now) that this could be caused by the use of single-channel SATA drives in a dual-channel SAS array. I don't know if this is true or not, but it's happening enough that I can't trust the array and need to do something.

So... I wonder if there's a "blank panel" that I could replace the unused controller in the array with so it won't think there are multiple paths. I've tried pulling out the extra controller, but that causes the fans to spin to full speed and the noise is excessive. I'm hoping there was a panel for these in the case where they were sold with only one controller.

If there was such a blank panel and you could point me to a part number, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm also open to other suggestions if I'm completely on the wrong track here.

Comment: That's a very old disk shelf - when did it go end of support?

Comment: Yes, it is old... and cheap.  This is in a home lab.   It performs very well overall, but it just hickups from time to time.

Comment: Right...as we make very clear in our help pages this isn't the place for home labs.

Comment: Get a few of SAS drives, put them in the array, and see if the problems disappear.  Used/refurb SAS drives can usually be found pretty cheap because not many businesses would buy them and home users can't use them.